# mosquitto MQTT parsing issue

Tags: c, json, mqtt, mosquitto, libmosquitto

I am using libmosquitto and the parson library in a C application running on my IoT device for doing stuff with MQTT and parsing JSON.

When I publish a message to my device using the mosquitto_pub command on a Linux terminal as follows :

```
mosquitto_pub -t "mytopic/test" -u "admin" -P "admin" -h 192.168.5.100 -m "{"value1": 1, "value2":  2, "value3":  3}"
```

I am succesfully receiving the message on the device as I am subscribed to it, however, I cannot parse the values at all using `json_object_dotget_value`

```
JSON_Value*  root_value   = json_parse_string(payload);
JSON_Object* root_object  = json_value_get_object(root_value);

JSON_Value* value1 =  json_object_dotget_value(root_object, "value1");
JSON_Value* value2 =  json_object_dotget_value(root_object, "value2");
JSON_Value* value3 =  json_object_dotget_value(root_object, "value3");
```

The values returned are NULL.

I know that i'm leaving out lots of code here. However, the problem is not on the receiving end, because when another application in Python publishes this message, the parsing works fine.

There is something wrong with my `mosquitto_pub` command, but I can't see it.

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: What does `payload` contain? That would be the first thing to start with. You say you receive it successfully, so it contains the sent message?

Comment: You may have to escape the `"` in the argument to your sender program (or use _single_ quotes): `-m "{"value1": 1, "value2":  2, "value3":  3}"` --> `-m '{"value1": 1, "value2":  2, "value3":  3}'`

Comment: @CraigEstey - That is the correct answer. Post it as an answer and get all the credit and glory!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per your comment, your *program* is fine.

In the *invocation*, you may have to escape the `"` in the argument to your sender program (or use *single* quotes)

With `-m "{"value1": 1, "value2":  2, "value3":  3}"`, the args [as the program sees them] are:

```
-m
{value1: 1, value2:  2, value3:  3}
```

Notice that the `"` got stripped around (e.g.) `value1` and json needs them.

So, change to `-m '{"value1": 1, "value2":  2, "value3":  3}'` and the args become:

```
-m
{"value1": 1, "value2":  2, "value3":  3}
```